# viewpager is hidden on some huawei&honor mobiles

Tags: android, android-viewpager, huawei-mobile-services

I have a problem with viewpager widget on some huawei&honor mobiles. The widget doesn't show on these mobiles, it is clickable and works, but it just doesn't show and is hidden. Those mobiles have a different android version.

Comment: You probably need to be more specific about your question - i.e. which Android version are you working with there.

Answer (score 1):

Viewpager is hidden in Huawei and glory mobile phones.
Viewpager, a view page flipping tool, provides the effect of multi page switching. A UI control introduced after Android 3.0 is located in the V4 package. It is necessary to import the V4 package for the use of the lower version, but now the app we developed is generally no longer compatible with the system version of 3.0 or below. In addition, most of the apps are developed using Android studio. The V7 package is imported by default, and V7 contains V4, so it is more and more convenient without package import.
Basic usage of viewpager: you can load an ImageView or a fragment in viewpager